# node.js setInterval doesn't work

Tags: node.js, socket.io, setinterval

With node.js, I'm trying to send the current `server_time` to all clients in every second.
Therefore, I wanted to use `setInterval()` to emit an event to all clients and sending the time, but it doesn't work. Did I define the `setInterval` function at the right place or did missed something else?

```
var http = require("http");
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var connect = require('connect');

//keep track of every connected client
var clients = {};

//create Server 
var httpServer = connect.createServer(
    connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8888);


//socket
var io = socketIO.listen(httpServer);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //add current client id to array
    clients[socket.id] = socket;
    socket.on('close', function() {
        delete clients[socket.fd]; // remove the client.
    });

    //send news on connection to client
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' }); 

    //this one works fine!
    //send server time on connection to client
    socket.emit("server_time", { time: new Date().toString() });

});

//this doesn't work!
// Write the time to all clients every second.
setInterval(function() { 
    var i, sock;
    for (i in clients) {
        sock = clients[i];
        if (sock.writable) { // in case it closed while we are iterating.
            sock.emit("server_time", {
                console.log("server_time sended");
                time: new Date().toString()

            });
        }
    }
}, 1000);       //every second
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there an error or do the messages simply not get emitted?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the line `console.log("server_time sended");`?

Comment: Put a console.log at the very top of your setInterval function (above var i, sock;). I think you'll find that it's getting called just fine,  but your clients array is empty or the socket isn't writeable.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details: there is no error, it's just that the data does not get emitted. it just seems like the setInterval is not executed at all.

Comment: @halex: removing console.log does not do anything.

Comment: @PherricOxide: thanks, you were right. i'm gonna see if i can fix the problem. any idea why the sockets are not writeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest a workaround/improvement that should fix the problem. Add the clients to a [chat room](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms). Somewhere in:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
```

add a

```
socket.join('timer');
```

Then the setIntervall would be

```
setInterval(function() { 
    io.sockets.in('timer').emit("server_time", { time: new Date().toString() })
}, 1000);
```

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the following function:

```
if (sock.writable) { // in case it closed while we are iterating.
  sock.emit("server_time", {
    // console.log("server_time sended"); // get rid of this line -> invalid code
    time: new Date().toString()
  });
}
```

`sock.writable` is `undefined` and therefore the `emit` event is never sent. Set the property to `true` on connection and to `false` on close.